# Unable to Add SQLite Datasource

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I'm using .NET Framework 4.6.2 for a WPF project. I'm adding System.Data.SQLite as a data provider. In App.config file it will update with this code:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)"
           invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6"
           description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)"
           type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider"
           invariant="System.Data.SQLite"
           description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite"
           type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Also update

```
<entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

I am trying to add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model. Then I get the error below:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is this link relevant?
https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/issues/389

Comment: Sorry, I'm also seeing this but it's not same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for this by installing an extension. That is [dotConnect ADO.NET Data Provider for SQLite](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DevartSoftware.dotConnectADONETDataProviderforSQLite).

It's working by providing an entity from the database.